# create a loop to copy cells

Tags: loops, copy, cells

iam trying to create a loop that copy some specific cells. I am fairly new to VBA but i can only get this to loop through the first row. The puropose of script is to copy specific cells in Sheet2736 to another excel sheet called pre. This should be done in all the cases where the specific condition is met. The code i have so far looks like this: 
Sub copypre1()

```
 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 2 To 50
 If Range("A" & i).Value = "Pre" Then

    Range("A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,S" & i).Select
    Range("S2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PRE Hedge").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("PRE Hedge").Select

  End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

well you should reselct the first sheet by changing your code to :

```
Sub copypre1()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 50
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "Pre" Then

            Range("A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,S" & i).Select
            Range("S" & i).Activate
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("PRE Hedge").Select
            Range("C" & (i+1)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Sheet2736").Select

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. I can see that i missed the part of going back to the first sheet after pasting the values. Though it says

"Method range of object failed" when it gets to line Range("A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,S" & i).Select